# How to bind property to hashmap

Tags: qt, syntax, qml

The following code prints `undefined`:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property var prop: {
        foo: 1
        bar: 2
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log(prop.foo);
    }
}
```

I guess the body of `prop` is interpreted as a JS code block, and `foo` and `bar` are interpreted as code labels.

I seem to remember that the Qt docs mention a gotcha: having to use double braces in such cases or something like that. But I can't find it right now.

What is the correct syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html):

```
property var prop: {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
}
```